# How to circumvent material ui radio button limitation of being placed in a parent wrapping element?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following react component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classes from './generalinfo.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { RadioButton, RadioButtonGroup } from 'material-ui/RadioButton';


class GeneralInfo extends Component {

    _ToggleNextScreenButton = (e) => {

        let currentState = this.props.infoObj;        

        let checkboxStatus =  Object.keys(currentState).map( (value) => {
            return currentState[value];
        });

        let ArroyOfCheckboxValues = checkboxStatus.filter((value) => {
            return value === false;
        });

        if(ArroyOfCheckboxValues.length > 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    } 

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={ classes.screen2 } >
                <table className={ classes.initial__survey__details__table }>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Gender    
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                    Age    
                            </td>     
                        </tr>     
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" name="genderRadio" value="male" 
                                       onChange={ (e) => { this.props.validateRadioInput({
                                           name  : e.target.getAttribute('name'), 
                                           value : e.target.getAttribute('value')
                                       }) }
                                    } />                                     
                                <label>Male</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" name="ageRadio" value="Less than 35" 
                                       onChange={ (e) => { this.props.validateRadioInput({
                                           name  : e.target.getAttribute('name'), 
                                           value : e.target.getAttribute('value')
                                       }) } } />                                   
                                <label>Less than 35</label>
                            </td>     
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" name="genderRadio" value="Female" 
                                       onChange={ (e) => { this.props.validateRadioInput({
                                           name  : e.target.getAttribute('name'), 
                                           value : e.target.getAttribute('value')
                                       }) } } />                                    
                                <label>Female</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" name="ageRadio" value="More than 35" 
                                       onChange={ (e) => { this.props.validateRadioInput({
                                           name  : e.target.getAttribute('name'), 
                                           value : e.target.getAttribute('value')
                                       }) } } />                                    
                                <label>More than 35</label>
                            </td>     
                        </tr> 
                        <tr>
                            <td colSpan="2">
                                <Link to="/preferences" className={ [classes.btn , classes["btn--fullwidth"] , classes.btn__next  ].join(' ') } 
                                        onClick={ (e) => this._ToggleNextScreenButton(e) } >
                                    Next
                                </Link>
                            </td>   
                        </tr>     
                    </tbody>   
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

(unnecessary parts intentionally deleted).

As you can see i have independent `radio` elements inside a `td` , now i wanted to add `radio` element but using `material-ui`, the problem is all the radio buttons of a specific group have to be grouped under a parent `<RadioButtonGroup />` as you can see below:

```
<RadioButtonGroup name="shipSpeed" defaultSelected="not_light">
      <RadioButton
        value="light"
        label="Simple"
        style={styles.radioButton}
      />
      <RadioButton
        value="not_light"
        label="Selected by default"
        style={styles.radioButton}
      />
      <RadioButton
        value="ludicrous"
        label="Custom icon"
        checkedIcon={<ActionFavorite style={{color: '#F44336'}} />}
        uncheckedIcon={<ActionFavoriteBorder />}
        style={styles.radioButton}
      />
    </RadioButtonGroup>
```

How can i circumvent this limitation of the radio button being placed inside a parent wrapper (I.E. i'd like to use the radio button with a parent wrapper ) and still use `material-ui` ?

Comment: The latest version of material-ui supports using Radio components standalone: https://material-ui-next.com/demos/selection-controls/#radio-buttons

Comment: @stone, still needs a parent wrapper `<RadioGroup
aria-label="gender" name="gender1" className={classes.group} value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} >` or else it will act more like a checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a wrapper for `RadioButton` and then use that wrapper instead of the original `RadioButton`:

```js
const TDRadioButton = ({wrapperProps, ...props}) => (
    <td {...wrapperProps}>
        <RadioButton {...props}>
    </td>
);
```

This will wrap every radio button into a `<td>` while preserving all of its functionality by forwarding the props.

Comment: can you show me  code demo of how this world work in a example ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Is there a special reason your radio buttons need to be in a table? This is quiet uncommon, especially the fact that the radio buttons belonging to the same group are not in the same row. If the table is used for layout purposes there are way better (and easier) solutions than that. If not you could make your life a lot easier if the radio buttons would be at least in the same row.